# Strange Bug When Using StickyListHeaders

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0 in my app and am getting a strange result. When I scroll down on the list view a certain header is shown "Attendance". However, when I scroll back up after passing that header to the next one "Cafeteria" is shown until that header is passed off. After Cafeteria is passed off, the Cafeteria suddenly turns back into Attendance in front of my eyes. There should actually be two different headers there, both Cafeteria and Attendance. Here is the code I am using for the list view adapter:

```
 List<StaffItem> itemList;

 @Override
public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    HeaderViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new HeaderViewHolder();
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.stafflistviewtextheader, null);
        holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        if (face1!=null)
            holder.itemTitle.setTypeface(face1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (HeaderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
 //set header text as first char in name
    headerText = itemList.get(position).getStafDepartment();
    holder.itemTitle.setText(headerText);
    return convertView;
}

    @Override
public long getHeaderId(int i) {
    if (itemList.get(i).getStafDepartment().length()>4){
    return itemList.get(i).getStafDepartment().charAt(4);}
    else if (itemList.get(i).getStafDepartment().length()>3){
        return itemList.get(i).getStafDepartment().charAt(3);}
    else if (itemList.get(i).getStafDepartment().length()>2){
        return itemList.get(i).getStafDepartment().charAt(2);}
    else if (itemList.get(i).getStafDepartment().length()>1){
        return itemList.get(i).getStafDepartment().charAt(1);}
    else if (itemList.get(i).getStafDepartment().length()>0){
        return itemList.get(i).getStafDepartment().charAt(0);}
    else{
    return 'a';}
}


class HeaderViewHolder {
    TextView itemTitle;
}
```

And the list item:

```
  public class StaffItem{

private final String stafDepartment;
private final String affiliation;
private final String webpage;
private final String email;
private final Boolean department;
private final String name;
public StaffItem(String staffDepartment, String affiliation , String webpage, String email, Boolean department, String name) {
    this.stafDepartment = staffDepartment; this.affiliation= affiliation; this.webpage= webpage;this.email= email; this.department= department;
    this.name= name;
}

public String getStafDepartment() {
    return stafDepartment;
}

public String getAffiliation(){return affiliation;}
public String getWebpage(){return webpage;}
public String getEmail(){return email;}
public Boolean getDepartment(){return department;}
public String getName(){return name;}



}
```